# Laravel4 unable to create a directory although I gave correct permissions

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Laravel4 unable to create a directory although I gave correct permissions.
FileException error happened, http://s28.postimg.org/xkor8srxp/2014_01_03_2_53_18.png.
I tried lots of permissions..

- sudo chmod -R 777 storage
- sudo chmod -R 707 storage
- sudo chmod -R o+rwx storage

and I even restarted Apache server.
I have been googling 24 hours or so, and still can't figure out..
Here are the routes and view files.

```
// routes.php

Route::post('handle-form', function()
{
    $name = Input::file('book')->getClientOriginalName();
Input::file('book')->move('/storage/directory', $name);
return 'File was moved.';
});

// form2.blade.php
<form action="{{ url('handle-form') }}"
  method="POST"
  enctype="multipart/form-data">

<input type="file" name="book" />
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Currently what I did to the routes.php by following your help,

```
Route::post('handle-form', function()
{
$name = Input::file('book')->getClientOriginalName();
Input::file('book')->move(public_path().'/storage/directory', $name); 
return 'File was moved.';
});
```

and the permission I gave was **sudo chmod -R 777 storage**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is what you can do to make it work:

Create a directory in your public folder, or any other place:

```
 mkdir -p /var/www/your-site-path/public/storage/directory
```

Make it writable by your webserver

```
sudo chmod 770 /var/www/your-site-path/public/storage/directory

sudo chown username:www-data /var/www/your-site-path/public/storage/directory
or
sudo chown dongju:httpd /var/www/your-site-path/public/storage/directory
```

Tell Laravel to write the file to that folder this way:

```
$name = Input::file('book')->getClientOriginalName();

Input::file('book')->move(public_path().'/storage/directory', $name);
```

Using this method I create here those two routes and it worked for me:

```
Route::get('form', function() {
    return 

        Form::open(array('url' => 'http://your-dev-server-address/upload', 'files' => true)) .

        Form::file('book', $attributes = array()) .

        Form::submit('submit') .

        Form::close();
});

Route::post('upload', function() {

    Input::file('book')->move(public_path().'/storage/directory', Input::file('book')->getClientOriginalName());

});
```

The first one `/form` will show you a file upload form and the second one `/upload` will get the file and save it to the correct path.

Comment: thank you for your reply. I already tried 'storage/directory' but still does not work. what debugging error logs do you need to take a look at?

Comment: Ok, I just completely edited my answer to give you all steps.

Comment: I do really appreciate your detailed explanations, but still does not work.

Comment: Sorry, but you'll have to be more specific, show us your folder and files structure. "it's not working" isn't enough even for guessing. Also you should take a look at your webserver and Laravel logs, they might be telling you what's happening. Just edited to show you what I did here to test and it worked.

Comment: geekerati is my home user on my Mac.
my directory structure is...
geekerati/Sites/learning-laravel/app/storage/directory

Comment: Also, I set a virtual host setting. So, my NameServer is laravel.dev and the DocumentRoot is indicating the public folder of the laravel project.

Comment: When I did Input::file('book')->move(public_path().'/storage/directory', $name);, this error was different. Now it says, Unable to write in the "/Users/geekerati/Sites/learning-laravel/public/storage/directory" directory

Comment: It's right, you just don't have right to write to it. You have to use the path `/Users/geekerati/Sites/learning-laravel/public/storage/directory`, just updated my answer so you can see it.

Comment: Oh wow.. It says it moved the file, but the file does not exist in that specified directory! I changed my permission with sudo chmod -R 707 storage, and then I used your code, Input::file('book')->move(public_path().'/storage/directory', $name);.

Comment: Change the path permissions to 777.

Comment: What do you have in that `$name` variable?

Comment: I did, and still it's writable as expected. However, the file was not uploaded actually.. http://s21.postimg.org/8elkci47b/2014_01_03_5_22_26.png

http://s24.postimg.org/8dylfrqg5/image.png

I just updated the snippet on the question section.

Comment: Test the move using `Input::file('book')->move(public_path().'/storage/directory', 'file.txt');`, and look at your logs if file wasn't written, something should appear in logs.

Comment: I tested it, and it didn't create that text file. :O

Comment: This answer really help me. In my case I had a folder that was in `app/storage/files/` and I thought that I had to gave the permissions to that folder. Later when I see this answer, I created a folder in `public/` called `files` and everything start to work. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was that I was using an environment variable which was not available at the time of making call so All I had to do was to change the variable I was using.

**In short please check the path you are specifying.**